# Rails Routes/Controller/Directory Structure design question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

I have a design question where I would appreciate a thoughtful response.

Let's say you have a simple application (for example's sake) that has a User, Company and Theme model. A Company `has_one` Theme and `has_many` Users.

Administrators (a User) can fully manage Companies, Users and Themes - the whole REST stack, in addition to a few other actions too. Administrators are expected to do things to all 3 of these resources that other user roles cannot do.

We also have a Company role. This role can edit their own Company, as well as select a Theme from the ones the admin-user added as nice defaults, or they can just make their own theme.

Companies can also add/edite/delete users, but only for their company. These pages will have different views and they'll have different behaviour from admins - some overlaps, but some things will be restricted while others will be added.

Now, here we have some non-trivial design choices, and I would like to know what the best-practice is.

**PART 1**

In Rails, it makes sense to have `resources :users, :companies, :themes` for the administrators and probably `resource :company, :theme, :users` for the Company users.

But of course, we run into some naming conflicts here - both singular and plural - so we might want to try something like `resource :my_company, :my_theme, :my_users` to separate them? Or is there a better solution?

Furthermore, a theme is just a component of a company, so maybe we want to nest them?

```
:resource :my_company do
  :resource :theme
  :resources :users
end
```

This works okay, but it could be confusing as to which UsersController we are referring to... no? This is really sticky and I would love to know how to deal with this. Do you have 1 controller, or 2? What do you name them?

So this would be an example:

```
http://myapp.com/my_company/theme/edit
http://myapp.com/my_company/users/1/delete
```

Company users also might want the list of themes via ajax, so is it correct for them to call:

```
http://myapp.com/themes.json
```

?

Is this how to approach this situation, or is there a better way?

**PART 2**

Also, what should your directory structure look? Should you have controllers separated by user role?

```
/app/controllers/admin/companies_controller.rb
/app/controllers/admin/themes_controller.rb
/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb
/app/controllers/company/my_company_controller.rb
/app/controllers/company/theme_controller.rb
/app/controllers/company/users_controller.rb
```

Or is there better ways to handle this?

It seems weird that users_controller is duplicated 2x and that there is a minor difference between Theme and Themes.

I would really appreciate a thoughtful response on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate your desire to organize your codebase as I constantly have to convince myself not to take my default impulse to nest a resource or namespace a model. As there is no right answer to this question, I will just offer the reasons I use to convince myself not to.

- A resource lives in once place. `User.find(1)` should have a single locator (URL), which I like to call user_path. I like calling it user_path because of all the times that I have made myself call it admin_company_user_path([@company, @user]) which malaise makes in me each time I write it.
- That resource may render itself in different ways for different situations, like if the requester was an XHR or indicated that they would prefer German to English. Why is the header indicating that the user is an administrator any different?
- If I can make it look like the simplest examples in the rails/README, shouldn't I?

At this point I would concede and end up with:

```
/app/controllers/companies_controller.rb
/app/controllers/users_controller.rb
/app/controllers/themes_controller.rb
```

And my routes.rb would have:

```
resources :users
resources :companies
resources :themes
```

I should also address how I would handle the thing that makes you want to separate them in the first place–a different view for each of the roles. In my ideal scenario, my decision would result in a `themes/_form.haml` that looks like:

```
= form.input :title if user_can_change_title?
= form.input :theme if user_can_change_theme?
```

And the rest of the differences would handled in CSS, with perhaps a stylesheet for each role.

In the less ideal scenario, I might be using:

```
= render :partial => "#{current_user.role}_form"
```

Comment: I don't think having 3 controllers and 'ifing' my way out of it will work :( A company user cannot manage 'themes' - and setting/customizing their theme has nothing to do with theme management options that an admin has access to - it's 180 degrees different. A user profile (both for the show and edit actions) is very different if you are a user from an admin. It may as well be a different model object. There's some overlap, and some not. Admins really don't care about many things, but the 3 company user roles all care about different things. I am thinking there would 'if' hell

Comment: I get what you mean here, but remember the mental weight is going to exist somewhere.. either in the additional files/classes you use to separate them, or in the conditionals. With regards to a company's theme and theme management, that seems to fit natually.. only admins can `edit_theme`, whereas company users can `edit_company` which allows them to select a theme. Definitely empathetic to your aversion to "if hell" though!